# Continue executing function

Tags: python, oop, tkinter, mainloop

When closing an instance of the `ChildWindow` class, which was called from another instance of `MainWindow`, the code does not continue to be executed.

I noticed that only when the `MainWindow` instance is closed does it continue to run. In general, it has a cumulative property, so the number of times the ChildWindow closes the window, the continuation will be displayed.

I want the function to continue executing when the ChildWindow closes, without closing the main window.
Here's my code:

```py
from tkinter import *

class MainWindow():

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        
    def run(self):
        Button(self.root, text='click', command=lambda:self.open_child_window()).pack()
        self.root.mainloop()

    def open_child_window(self):
        A = ChildWindow()
        A.run()
        print("why i'm not write?")

class ChildWindow():

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Toplevel()

    def run(self):
        self.root.mainloop()


A = MainWindow()
A.run()
```

It seems to me that this is due to the `self.root.mainloop()` loop, so I was looking for how to stop it, the `.quit()`, `.destroy()` methods do not help.

Comment: You shouldn't be calling `Tk()` more than once - that creates the entire GUI environment (with limitations on how those environments can interact with each other), not just a window.  You want `Toplevel()` for that.

Comment: @jasonharper, this doesn't work either :(

Comment: You should also be running *one* event loop.

Comment: @chepner, I ran into the same problem. Intended .mainloop() prevents further execution

Comment: You should be able to continue with calling `self.root.quit()` from a button for example. Anyway, there is `wait_window` or `wait_variable` for this taks but be aware of what it does. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74370984/is-tkwait-wait-variable-wait-window-wait-visibility-broken

Comment: @chepner, FYI, a nested loop is fine. See my answer.

Comment: As an aside: writing `lambda: x()` is like writing `[x][0]` - either way, just write `x` instead. `lambda` is for when the function needs to be adapted (i.e., change the parameters, by ignoring some of what is passed in or by calculating more things to pass).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called a nested event loop or modal loop. Use the `mainloop()` and `quit()` like this.

```
class ChildWindow():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Toplevel()

    def run(self):
        win = self.root
        def on_close():
            win.destroy()
            win.quit()
        win.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', on_close)
        win.mainloop()
        print('end of the nested loop')
...
```

You can also use `wait_window()` and `destroy()` like this.(The former runs a nested event loop until the window is destroyed.)

```
class ChildWindow():
    ...
    def run(self):
        win = self.root
        def on_close():
            win.destroy()
        win.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', on_close)
        win.wait_window()
```

Comment: I was already told about the `wait_window` method, but this method also works. Somehow I'm even surprised that it works, because I already tried it. But anyway, thanks :D

Comment: apparently it's all about the `win.destroy` and `win.quit` methods, because I tried to use them separately...

Comment: A solution using the ```wait_window()``` was added. Thanks.